# Draw text on image

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I'm trying to draw text on image using the below code :

```
procedure TfMain.TextToImage(const AText: string; const AImage: TImage);
begin
  if NOT Assigned(AImage) then Exit;    
  AImage.Canvas.BeginScene;
  AImage.Canvas.Font.Size    := 18;
  AImage.Canvas.Font.Family  := 'Arial';
  AImage.Canvas.Fill.Color   := TAlphaColorRec.Dodgerblue;
  AImage.Canvas.Font.Style   := [TFontStyle.fsbold];
  AImage.Canvas.FillText( AImage.AbsoluteRect,
                          AText,
                          False,
                          1,
                          [TFillTextFlag.RightToLeft],
                          TTextAlign.taCenter,
                          TTextAlign.taCenter);
  AImage.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

Q: Why the above procedure works on Windows but not in android ?

Comment: Are you sure `android` tag is attached appropriately?

Comment: @azizbekian I guess so, Did you read my Q ? Or you just looked at the code :)

Comment: In Android we can do this through custom views and we need to add All TTF file which want applied into  text in android.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to draw directly on the `TBitmap` of the timage instead of the Canvas of the TImage.

You need also to create a bitmap of your image before you try to access it:

```
AImage.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(Round(AImage.Width), Round(AImage.Height));
```

So the correct code will be something like this:

```
procedure TfMain.TextToImage(const AText: string; const AImage: TImage);
begin
  if NOT Assigned(AImage) then Exit;
  AImage.Bitmap := TBitmap.Create(Round(AImage.Width), Round(AImage.Height));
  AImage.Bitmap.Canvas.BeginScene;
  try
    //....
    // Use AImage.Bitmap.Canvas as needed
    AImage.Bitmap.Canvas.FillText( AImage.AbsoluteRect,
                            AText,
                            False,
                            1,
                            [],
                            TTextAlign.Center,
                            TTextAlign.Center);
  finally
    AImage.Bitmap.Canvas.EndScene;
  end;
end;
```

From the `TImage.Paint` event code you will see:

```
procedure TImage.Paint;
var
  R: TRectF;
begin
  if (csDesigning in ComponentState) and not Locked and not FInPaintTo then
  begin
    R := LocalRect;
    InflateRect(R, -0.5, -0.5);
    Canvas.DrawDashRect(R, 0, 0, AllCorners, AbsoluteOpacity, $A0909090);
  end;

  UpdateCurrentBitmap;
  if FCurrentBitmap <> nil then
    DrawBitmap(Canvas, LocalRect, FCurrentBitmap, AbsoluteOpacity);
end;
```

So no matter what you will paint on the canvas, on the next repaint it will draw again the full bitmap erasing what you already done.

If you don't want to touch the bitmap than you need to override the `OnPaint` event of the`TImage` and call `function TextToImage(const AText: string; const AImage: TImage);`

Answer (score 0):

See below Custom Class for `ImageView` with Text in Android.But Need to Ass TTF or OTF file for more typfaces.

```
package com.fuzzydev;

import com.fuzzydev.labeledimageview.R;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ImageView;

/*
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * "THE BEER-WARE LICENSE" (Revision 42):
 * As long as you retain this notice you
 * can do whatever you want with this stuff. If we meet some day, and you think
 * this stuff is worth it, you can buy me a beer in return Dejan Ristic
 * ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
 */

public class LabeledImageView extends ImageView {

    private static final String TAG = "LabeledImageView";

    private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_STYLE = Typeface.NORMAL;
    private static final int DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR = Color.WHITE;
    private static final int DEFAULT_SCREEN_LOCATION = 0;
    private static final int DEFAULT_X_OFFSET = 30;
    private static final int DEFAULT_Y_OFFSET = 30;

    private static final float DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE = 40f;

    private float textSize;
    private float xPos, yPos;
    private float xOffset, yOffset;

    private int labelLocation;
    private int textStyle;
    private int textColor;

    private String text;
    private String customFont;

    private Paint mTextPaint;

    public LabeledImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initWithDefautls();
    }

    public LabeledImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initWithAttrs(attrs, context);
    }

    private void initWithDefautls() {
        textSize = DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE;
        textStyle = DEFAULT_TEXT_STYLE;
        textColor = DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR;
        labelLocation = DEFAULT_SCREEN_LOCATION;
        xOffset = DEFAULT_X_OFFSET;
        yOffset = DEFAULT_Y_OFFSET;
        setTextPaint();
    }

    private void initWithAttrs(AttributeSet attrs, Context context) {
        initAttrs(context, attrs);
        setTextPaint();
        if (customFont != null) {
            setCustomFont(context);
        }
    }

    private void initAttrs(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        TypedArray a = context.getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                R.styleable.LabeledImageView, 0, 0);

        try {
            text = a.getString(R.styleable.LabeledImageView_text);
            textSize = a.getFloat(R.styleable.LabeledImageView_textSizePx,
                    DEFAULT_TEXT_SIZE);
            textStyle = a.getInt(R.styleable.LabeledImageView_textStyle,
                    DEFAULT_TEXT_STYLE);
            textColor = a.getInt(R.styleable.LabeledImageView_textColor,
                    DEFAULT_TEXT_COLOR);
            labelLocation = a.getInt(
                    R.styleable.LabeledImageView_labelPosition,
                    DEFAULT_SCREEN_LOCATION);
            customFont = a.getString(R.styleable.LabeledImageView_customFont);
            xOffset = a.getFloat(R.styleable.LabeledImageView_xOffset,
                    DEFAULT_X_OFFSET);
            yOffset = a.getFloat(R.styleable.LabeledImageView_yOffset,
                    DEFAULT_Y_OFFSET);
            ;
        } finally {
            a.recycle();
        }
    }

    private void setCustomFont(Context ctx) {
        Typeface tf = null;
        try {
            tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(ctx.getAssets(), customFont);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not get typeface: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(tf);
    }

    private void setLabelLocation() {

        switch (labelLocation) {
        case 0: // Top Left
            xPos = xOffset;
            yPos = yOffset;
            break;
        case 1: // Top Right
            xPos = getWidth() - mTextPaint.measureText(text) - xOffset;
            yPos = yOffset;
            break;
        case 2: // Bottom Left
            xPos = xOffset;
            yPos = getHeight() - yOffset;
            break;
        case 3: // Bottom Right
            xPos = getWidth() - mTextPaint.measureText(text) - xOffset;
            yPos = getHeight() - yOffset;
            break;
        case 4: // Top Center
            xPos = (getWidth() / 2) - (mTextPaint.measureText(text) / 2);
            yPos = yOffset;
            break;
        case 5: // Bottom Center
            xPos = (getWidth() / 2) - (mTextPaint.measureText(text) / 2);
            yPos = getHeight() - yOffset;
            break;
        case 6: // Center
            xPos = (getWidth() / 2) - (mTextPaint.measureText(text) / 2);
            yPos = (getHeight() / 2);
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
        setLabelLocation();
    }

    private void setTextPaint() {
        mTextPaint = new Paint();
        mTextPaint.setTextSize(textSize);
        mTextPaint.setColor(textColor);
        mTextPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.defaultFromStyle(textStyle));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        if (text != null) {
            canvas.drawText(text, xPos, yPos, mTextPaint);
        }
    }

    public void setTextSize(float textSize) {
        this.textSize = textSize;
    }

    public void setCustomFont(String customFont) {
        this.customFont = customFont;
    }

    public void setLabelLocation(int labelLocation) {
        this.labelLocation = labelLocation;
    }

    public void setyOffset(float yOffset) {
        this.yOffset = yOffset;
    }

    public void setxOffset(float xOffset) {
        this.xOffset = xOffset;
    }

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public void setTextStyle(int textStyle) {
        this.textStyle = textStyle;
    }

    public void setTextColor(int textColor) {
        this.textColor = textColor;
    }
}
```

See Implementation of above class in this

https://github.com/DejanRistic/LabeledImageView/tree/master/src/com/fuzzydev

link

Comment: Does this look like  Delphi  code to you? The question is clearly tagged *Delphi*, so a Java solution doesn't really help much.